# How can I read the orientation of screen using NotificationCenter after running app and save it

Tags: swift, swiftui

currently I am using this down code for reading orientation, but when I run the app, in some how way iOS or NotificationCenter is unable to tell the orientation! it says: "**unknown**", how can I be sure that I got the right value in **first attempt** my salutation was putting a timer and reading the orientation until I get **isPortrait** or **isLandscape**, then I dismiss the timer, but that look not a good coding, what is best way for this, can I use kind of *escaping closure*/(or: *completion handler*) for this? Like when we got the right value then send it via closure otherwise wait for value!

Also I tried save the read value in a variable `orientationOfDevice`, but I am getting this compile time error:

`Instance member 'orientationOfDevice' cannot be used on type 'OrientationModel'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var orientationModel: OrientationModel = OrientationModel()

    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: orientationModel.orientationOfDevice) { newValue in print(newValue) }
  
    }
}
```

---

```
class OrientationModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var orientationOfDevice: String = String()
    
    private let notification = NotificationCenter
        .default
        .addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
            
            if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait { print("isPortrait") }
            else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape { print("isLandscape") }
            else { print("unknown") }
            
            
            //if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait { orientationOfDevice = "isPortrait" }
            //else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape { orientationOfDevice = "isLandscape" }
            //else { orientationOfDevice = "unknown" }
            
        }
    
    deinit { NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notification) }
    
}
```

Comment: Note that _device_ orientation is _not_ the same as screen/app orientation and is very unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Yes I know, my main question is about why I get no value at first read? and why I cannot save it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaorund, you can fallback to use this if the `orientation.isPortrait` returned unknown:

```
var isPortrait: Bool {
    UIScreen.main.bounds.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

Why does that code work? Because `.width` doesnt always represent the the smaller dimension of the device. Instead, it always represents the lower part of the device:

```
            Landscape
    ____________________________
    |                          |
    |                          |
    |     Your Device :)       |
    |                          |
    |__________________________|
               ↑↑↑
        This is the `.width`

And:

             Portrait
         _______________
         |             |
         |             |
         |             |
         |             |
         | Your Device |
         |             |
         |             |
         |             |
         |             |
         |_____________|
                ↑↑↑
       This is still the `.width`
```

So you can see, if the `.width` is smaller than `.height`, then the device must be in Portrait mode, and if `.width` is bigger that `.height`, then the device must be in Landscape mode.

Comment: I do not want replace the codes to solve the issue, I want to solve the issue, why I must get unknown at first attempt? And If it is fact and must happen, how could I use the codes in my question to read the right value, and how can I save it, it seems your answer has not mentioned those 3 points.

Comment: This is a known issue from what i found in other stackoverflow answers, and other people recommended similar workarounds like the one i did.

Comment: if this unknown must or should be an old bug of Swift, I want try to read the correct value if we read unknown in first try, the idea was not never use another way.